# Atomic counter in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

I must be just having a moment, because this should be easy but I can't seem to get it working right.

Whats the correct way to implement an atomic counter in GCC?

i.e. I want a counter that runs from zero to 4 and is thread safe.

I was doing this (which is further wrapped in a class, but not here)

```
static volatile int _count = 0;
const int limit = 4;

int get_count(){
  // Create a local copy of diskid
  int save_count = __sync_fetch_and_add(&_count, 1);
  if (save_count >= limit){
      __sync_fetch_and_and(&_count, 0); // Set it back to zero
  }
  return save_count;
}
```

But it's running from 1 through from 1 - 4 inclusive then around to zero.
It should go from 0 - 3.  Normally I'd do a counter with a mod operator but I don't
know how to do that safely.

Perhaps this version is better.  Can you see any problems with it, or offer
a better solution.

```
int get_count(){
   // Create a local copy of diskid
   int save_count = _count;
   if (save_count >= limit){
      __sync_fetch_and_and(&_count, 0); // Set it back to zero
      return 0;
   }

   return save_count;
 }
```

Actually, I should point out that it's not absolutely critical that each thread get a different value.  If two threads happened to read the same value at the same time that wouldn't be a problem.  But they can't exceed limit at any time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code isn't atomic (and your second `get_count` doesn't even increment the counter value)!

Say `count` is 3 at the start and two threads simultaneously call `get_count`. One of them will get his atomic add done first and increments `count` to 4. If the second thread is fast enough, it can increment it to `5` before the first thread resets it to zero.

Also, in your wraparound processing, you reset `count` to 0 but not `save_count`. This is clearly not what's intended.

This is easiest if `limit` is a power of 2. Don't ever do the reduction yourself, just use

```
return (unsigned) __sync_fetch_and_add(&count, 1) % (unsigned) limit;
```

or alternatively

```
return __sync_fetch_and_add(&count, 1) & (limit - 1);
```

This only does one atomic operation per invocation, is safe and very cheap. For generic limits, you can still use `%`, but that will break the sequence if the counter ever overflows. You can try using a 64-bit value (if your platform supports 64-bit atomics) and just hope it never overflows; this is a bad idea though. The proper way to do this is using an atomic compare-exchange operation. You do this:

```
int old_count, new_count;
do {
  old_count = count;
  new_count = old_count + 1;
  if (new_count >= limit) new_count = 0; // or use %
} while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&count, old_count, new_count));
```

This approach generalizes to more complicated sequences and update operations too.

That said, this type of lockless operation is tricky to get right, relies on undefined behavior to some degree (all current compilers get this right, but no C/C++ standard before C++0x actually has a well-defined memory model) and is easy to break. I recommend using a simple mutex/lock unless you've profiled it and found it to be a bottleneck.

Comment: Whether __sync_fetch_and_add "does one atomic operation per invocation" depends on the CPU - unspecified in the question.  It may well be implemented as per your compare-and-swap approach, which is what I've used on Sun hardware in the past (well, my ex-colleague's implementation, cutely named "atomic_robin" :-)).

Comment: I wasn't talking about the number of instructions executed; there's different ways to implement exchange-add, but they're all equivalent as long as they only actually write to memory ("commit") once. The point is that you can't build one "big" atomic primitives out of several small ones; they don't compose. You can use multiple steps, but the final (commit) step must be a single atomic operation that makes everything visible. If there's more than one such step at the end, you automatically have a race condition.

Comment: Hey thanks.  This is exactly what I'm after. Don't know quite what I was thinking with my second solution.  I guess it was the lack of sleep that made me write such good code.

Comment: I don't understand why the sequence will break if the counter overflows with a non power-of-2 limit. Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 3):

You're in luck, because the range you want happens to fit into exactly 2 bits.

Easy solution: Let the volatile variable count up forever.  But after you read it, use just the lowest two bits (`val & 3`).  Presto, atomic counter from 0-3.

Comment: @Inverse: mod's can be much slower... & is a safer bet.

Comment: That's a good point.  Although I need the value of limit to be arbitrary.  It comes from a configuration file.

Comment: @Tony: I'm pretty sure a compiler can optimize `x % 4` to `x & 3`

Comment: Yes, a compiler will optimize `x % 4` to `x & 3`.  But don't be fooled into thinking that because `%` accepts an rhs which is not a power-of-2, that it would be more general.  In fact, my optimization only works for powers-of-2 because when the counter finally does overflow, it will count in sequence for power-of-2 but skip for any other modulo.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to create anything atomic in pure C, even with `volatile`. You need asm. C1x will have special atomic types, but until then you're stuck with asm.

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have tagged it as C.  This is C++, not using c1x though.

Comment: Pure C, sure, but he's tagged gcc as well, so intrinsics/builtins are the best option.

Comment: Link and reference to atomic types for +1, as it will be useful in a number of years.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

`__sync_fetch_and_add` will return the ***previous*** value (i.e., before adding one). So at the step where `_count` becomes 3, your local `save_count` variable is getting back `2`. So you actually have to increment `_count` up to `4` before it'll come back as a `3`.

But even on top of that, you're specifically looking for it to be `>= 4` before you reset it back to 0. That's just a question of using the wrong limit if you're only looking for it to get as high as three.